# Cannot create new Device in AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to add a new device using AVD Manager (**not** Android Virtual Device but in **Device Definitions tab**). I just installed a brand new version of the Eclipse (Luna) and the Android SDK (r23.0.2) under Windows 7 64 bit OS.

I then open the AVD Manager strait from the SDK folder and choose the Device Definitions tab.
In that tab I press the 'Create Device...' button, fill every field needed in the dialog that opened. The button 'Create Device' in that dialog is becoming enabled and I press it...
Nothing happens. The dialog is not closing and the device is not added to the list.

I saw very similar questions regarding creating a virtual device and tried to apply the suggestions made there but with no success. Added the path to java and SDK tools and platform tools in the PATH environment variable, choose a name with no spaces.. nothing helps.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Just found out that there is an open bug report on this exact issue:**

[Issue 73648 - Create new device definition broke](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73648&q=AVD%20Device&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

There's a workaround. Hope it will be fixed soon

Comment: As mentioned in a separate answer, the workaround is to select one of the stock device definitions and click the "Clone..." button. This will create a separate definition, which can be edited and saved. As of SDK Tools version 23.0.5, which I just tested on Windows, including spaces in the name of the device definition is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this path:

C:\Users\"your PC name".android\avd

Have you and file in this folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had (or have) the same problem-'Create Device' does nowt. As a simpler workaround you can use the 'clone...' option which brings up the same dialog

Answer (score 0):

Yes, select any device from the available and click on clone , and change the parameters. 
New Device will be added successfully.